# How to calculate mean and standard deviation from median and quartiles

Tags: r, self-study, mean, quantiles

I have 1st quartile, median and 3rd quartile. I want to find mean and SD. I want to use Bland’s method<sup>[1](http://www.lifescienceglobal.com/pms/index.php/ijsmr/article/download/2688/1576)</sup> but i do not have max, min values of the data. How can i solve this problem? Is there any R package?

<sup>[1](http://www.lifescienceglobal.com/pms/index.php/ijsmr/article/download/2688/1576)</sup> Bland, Martin. 2014. “Estimating Mean and Standard Deviation from the Sample Size, Three Quartiles, Minimum, and Maximum.” [*International Journal of Statistics in Medical Research* **4** (1)](http://www.lifescienceglobal.com/pms/index.php/ijsmr/article/download/2688/1576): 57–64.

Comment: Without some knowledge of the population distribution you cannot determine the mean.  If the mean exists it doesn't even have to fall between the first and third quartile.

Comment: If you have literally nothing else, then why do you think it's either necessary or useful to estimate the mean and SD? What would do with them?

Comment: I recently posted data sets where the mean didn't even lay between the 10th and 90th percentiles... without additional assumptions that rule out such possibilities, this is not going to give sensible answers.

Comment: I'd flag the simple points that one should always (1) flag that this is at best an approximation to be treated very circumspectly (2) cite median and quartiles explicitly or make them accessible otherwise (3) use the spacing of the quartiles around the median as a check on symmetry (4) use what else is known about the measurement scale: even when minimum and maximum are not known there should be some idea of theoretical or likely limits.

Answer (score 11):

You can check Wan *et al.* (2014)<sup>*</sup>. They build on Bland (2014) to estimate these parameters according to the data summaries available. See scenario *C<sub>3</sub>* in their paper :

$$ \bar{X} ≈ \frac {q_{1} + m + q_{3}}{3}$$

$$ S ≈ \frac {q_{3} - q_{1}}{1.35}$$

or, if you have the sample size :

$$ S ≈ \frac {q_{3} - q_{1}}{2 \Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{0.75n-0.125}{n+0.25}\right) }$$

where $q_{1}$ is the first quartile, $m$ the median, $q_{3}$ is the 3<sup>rd</sup> quartile and $\Phi^{-1}(z)$ the upper z<sup>th</sup> percentile of the standard normal
distribution.

So, in R :

```r
q1 <- 0.02
q3 <- 0.04
n <- 100

(s <- (q3 - q1) / (2 * (qnorm((0.75 * n - 0.125) / (n + 0.25)))))
#[1] 0.0150441
```

---

<sup>* Wan, Xiang, Wenqian Wang, Jiming Liu, and Tiejun Tong. 2014. “Estimating the Sample Mean and Standard Deviation from the Sample Size, Median, Range And/or Interquartile Range.” *BMC Medical Research Methodology* **14** (135). doi:[10.1186/1471-2288-14-135](http://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-135).</sup>

Comment: No matter how you slice it these papers assume the sample comes fro a normal distribution.  Then the population mean=median and of course it is between the 1st and 3rd quartiles!  But nowhere did the OP assume normality.

Comment: They test their formulas on normal and skewed data ; but I'm no specialist...

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Michael Chernick's comment, here's an example.

```
x <- runif(1000,0,1)
summary(x)  #1st Q = 0.27  3rd = 0.77  mean = .51

x1 <- c(x,100)
summary(x1) #1Q = 0.27  3rd = 0.77  mean = .61

x2 <- c(rnorm(100,0,1), rnorm(10,10,.1))
summary(x2)  # 1st = -.85  3rd = 0.69, mean = 0.71
```

With the first pair, note that a single outlier affects the mean but not the quartiles.  The last example is one where the mean is larger than the 3rd quartile.

One real world case where the mean could be greater than the third quartile is income.

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed publication on this topic from [Greco et al, How to impute study-specific standard deviations in meta-analyses of skewed continuous endpoints? World Journal of Meta-Analysis 2015;3(5):215-224](http://www.wjgnet.com/2308-3840/full/v3/i5/215.htm).

The main findings of this work are that it is acceptable to approximate "missing values of mean and SD with the correspondent values for median and interquartile range".

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the data is normally distributed, you can infer it given the lower and upper quantiles.

```r
norm_from_quantiles = function(lower, upper, p = 0.25) {
  mu = mean(c(lower, upper))
  sigma = (lower - mu) / qnorm(p)
  list(mu = mu, sigma = sigma)
}
```

Here, `p` and `1-p` are the quantiles of `lower` and `upper` so `p = 0.25` is quartiles while `p = 0.1` would mean that `lower` and `upper` are 10% and 90% quantiles respectively.

Answer (score -2):

I faced similar problem , where i calculated percentiles (0 to 100%) and then I was asked to give back mean as well , after playing in my notebook i noticed that the empirical mean of the quantiles list is in fact the mean of the distribution , thought i discovered a new theorem hahah but then found this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

The theorem established that if you consider F-1 X(w) a random variable and you sample randomly in [0,1] then take the corresponding X , you can generate samples this way from the original distribution , that's why i was getting the mean when computing the quantiles mean .
It's not mentioned directly but if you can generate samples of the original distribution then their mean is the mean of the original distribution .

Comment: Although this is sort of correct--both of your methods *approximate* or *estimate* the mean, rather than compute it--it doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: That's fine provided you clearly disclose that this is an approximation and is not exactly right. Your statement "is in fact" appears deceptive in that regard.  Ordinarily, any good approximation is also accompanied by an estimate of *how* good it might be.

Comment: When someone claims "1.9 = 2," that statement needs elaboration or else it should just be rejected out of hand.  It's that simple.'

Comment: reread my comment , i think i elaborated enough , you remind me of an old teacher of mine , he always used to focus on useless things , instead of teaching me something useful , everyone who reads that understand that it's an approximation , and with the help of my elaboration he understands why it works.

Comment: Enough.  If you won't clarify your answer, I will at least warn future readers (-1).

Comment: On the contrary, many distributions have no density but their expectations can be computed.  It comes down to what information you have about them, but *all* distributions have characteristic functions and cumulative distribution functions, from which any moment can be determined.

Comment: It is time to stop attacking me personally.  You are totally wrong in all your guesses and insinuations, but that doesn't matter.  Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/conduct for information about our expectations for your conduct here.